# Random / Spam likes on a company Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Recently over the past couple of months I've been seeing more and more likes on a Facebook company page I manage. When looking at the profiles that are liking the page a very high proportion of the likes seem to have no relation to the page. In the past week this has been becoming more frequent.

I've heard in the past about spam bots liking random pages as part of a paid like campaign (they like the random pages as to not make their paid likes look obvious and hide the actual page they are liking). I'm not sure if this is what's happening here, but its the only conclusion I can draw.

- Is there any danger of the company page being marked as spam because of this? (Looking at the likes section of the Facebook page its says the page now has 225 likes, 45 of which are in the last week, this is a page that has been live for about 3 years, with very little activity, it had probably 30-50 likes at the beginning of this year)
- Is there any thing that can be done to counteract this ?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Just started experiencing the same problem and worried someone is trying to get our page taken down...

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source of the likes by going to Insights->Likes and scrolling to the bottom of the page, with *Where Your Page Likes Happened*. Chances are that most of the abnormal likes are from Page Suggestions, shown in blue as on the screenshot below.

[image: pagesugg]

This means that Facebook algorithm, in its infinite wisdom, decided to suggest your page to some users. You wouldn't be marked as spam because of this, since the users are real. They just like clicking buttons on Facebook...

But if you want to prevent this, go to Settings->General and uncheck the box at

> Similar Page Suggestions...  Include [your page name] when recommending similar Pages people might like on a Page timeline.

[Zest Digital](http://www.zestdigital.com/facebook-page-suggestions-like-explosion/) goes into some details on this.